# How to get data from <a> tag value into Controller in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

I want to make my post order by user's choice.

> 1. Post Order by Like Rate.
> 2. Post Order by Date.

So here is my ***index.blade.php*** code

```
<li class="dropdown text-right" id="orderlist" name="order"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Post Order <span class="caret"></span></a>

       <ul class="dropdown-menu">
           <li><a value="polike" id="like">By Like</a></li>
           <li><a value="podate" id="date">By Date</a></li>
       </ul>
</li>
```

I want to get that Value from both of < a > tag and carry that values with variable to Controller.

Here is my controller Code.

```
//Logic order by
        $value="value from inded.blade.php"
        $order=$value;

        if($order=="bydate"){ //Order by post date
            orderBy('created_at','desc')
        }
        else{ //Order by Like Rating.
            $infos=Funs::bubblesort($infos);
        }
```

Thank you for your helping. Please help me.

Comment: You can do that with a form that point to an action of your controller

Comment: Can you show me detail please. Thanks for ur help.

Comment: I would recommend following some tutorials for laravel and PHP, you seem to have some lack of experience to get started with something for now. I would recommend creating an account at laracast aswell to continue learning.

Comment: The answer down here by @Alexey Mezenin Might help. But if you don't want a HTTP GET then an AJAX request could be a good option

Answer (score 2):

You can build your links so they will pass `GET` parameter:

```
<li><a href="post?order=like">By Like</a></li>
<li><a href="post?order=date">By Date</a></li>
```

Then in a model you can create `order()` [local scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#local-scopes):

```
public function scopeOrder($q)
{
    if (!empty(request()->order)) { 
        $q = request()->order == 'like' ? $q->orderBy('like', 'desc') : $q;
        $q = request()->order == 'date' ? $q->orderBy('date', 'desc') : $q;
    }

    return $q;
}
```

And then use it:

```
Model::order()->get();
```

Comment: 'Model::order()->get();'  where should i use it? In controller? Please explain me. I'm noob.

Comment: You can do it in controller, but it's better to create a method in a model and return mentioned code from it. Then call the method from a controller.

Comment: I post my codes photo under comment. Please check me and explain me how should i do to work codes. Please.